# Toggle a button if some other button have a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable/enable (toggle) a button if 1 or more other buttons have the class `.selected`

I've tried this but only works if one button is selected

```js
$('body').on("click", "button.item-select", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let maxItems = 2;
    let Items = $('button.item-select.selected').length;

    if(Items < maxItems) {
        $(this).toggleClass('select');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('select');
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }

    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $('.change-this').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('.change-this').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger change-this" disabled>Disabled/enabled</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-select">First</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-select">Second</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-select">Third</button>
```

Is there a way to enable the button only when one of the buttons have the class `.selected` and otherwise keep it disabled?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f56mzkae/

Comment: let me understand it better: the button `"Disabled/enabled"` must be enabled if two or more other buttos have the class `.selected`, and must be disabled if less than two have the class?

Comment: It must be disabled if other buttons don't have the class 'selected'. Right now, it only works with 1 button, if I select 2 buttons then deselect one, the button with class change-this will change to disabled, but I want it to remain enabled if some other buttons have the class 'selected'

Comment: Sorry, I still not understanding, It's a bit confusing to understand which button must do what

Comment: The button with the class `change-this` is disabled by default, the other 3 with the class `item-select` have `selected` class added to them when clicked. If this 3 buttons have the class `selected`, `change-this` will become `enabled`, `disabled` otherwise

Comment: You mean `change-this` button should be enabled only when all three buttons `item-select` have class `selected`?

Comment: It should be enabled only when one or more `item-select` have the class `selected`

Comment: Jesus, each comment you say a different thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on your explanation on comments:

When a button is clicked, I toggle the `.selected` class on that button, then I select all buttons that have this class, if the length is 1 or more, then I enable the `change-this` button, otherwise, I disable it.

Take a look.

```js
$('body').on("click", "button.item-select", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('select');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    
    let itemsSelected = $('.selected').length;

    if(itemsSelected >= 1) {     
      $('.change-this').prop("disabled", false);      
    }
    else{
      $('.change-this').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.selected{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger change-this" disabled>Disabled/enabled</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-select">First</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-select">Second</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-select">Third</button>
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I don't know why I spent so much on this, I think I was overthinking it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler way of doing what you need.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if(target.matches('.btn-primary')) { 
    target.classList.toggle('item-select');
  }
  
  document.querySelector('.btn-danger').disabled = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary'))
                                                       .some(b => b.classList.contains('item-select'));
});
```

```css
.item-select {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger change-this">Disabled/enabled</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">First</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Second</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Third</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I understood your question.`change-this` button becomes enabled only when all three `item-select` buttons have class `selected`.
So, we listen for click on any `item-select` button and add class `selected` as soon as we get click. And at the same time we check if all three buttons have class `selected` now.

```
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('item-select')) {
        // then the click was on one of the .item-select buttons
        // toggle .selected class to it
        event.target.classList.toggle('selected');

        // and each time buttons are clicked
        // check if they all have class .selected
        let count = document.querySelectorAll('.item-select.selected').length;

        if (count === 3) {
            document.querySelector('.change-this').removeAttribute('disabled');
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.change-this').setAttribute('disabled', '');
        }

    }
});
```

P.S.: Sorry, I'm not strong at jQuery, so used pure JS.